# React native animation => new Animated.Value() with useState or not?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

What is the best way to use Animated.Value () in react-native ?

With useState() or not ?

```
const [fadeAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
```

Or

```
const fadeAnim = new Animated.Value(0)
```

React-native doc: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually , Hook are a better way , so i'd say first choise

Comment: can you explain why ?
Use useState without a "setX" seems to be a little bit weird

Comment: Hook and not Hook are the same. Actually Hook are more malleable, because u can  keep u code more clean and , for example , u can invent property to pass to another scrren page , or render a single item of itemlist in a separated file.
The concept is the same , but change only in grammatic

Answer (score 7):

I've been using this recently:

```js
const [fadeAnim] = useState(() => new Animated.Value(0));
```

and for set value the standard:

```js
fadeAnim.setValue(0);
```

Also, you might want to look at `useRef` too, since it is what [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations) recommend:

```js
const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
/* 
... 
*/
fadeAnim.setValue(0);
```

Comment: fadeAnim.setValue is not a function

Comment: @nishi it's a method. https://reactnative.dev/docs/animatedvalue#setvalue

Answer (score 3):

I came across a dodgy UI bug where settings hook values would render in the view instantly and mess up the animations. I fixed this by putting putting the animation value in a useState hook like so:

Before:

```
const foo = new Animated.Value(1)
```

After:

```
  const [foo] = useState(new Animated.Value(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `useRef()` as recommended in

https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated

https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations#animated-api.

```
const [fadeAnim] = useState(() => new Animated.Value(0));
```

It is same but semantically `"state"` means `getter` and `setter` - without `setter` `'fadeAnim'` will be same throughout the component's lifetime so no different than `useRef(...).current`